# Java regex split string after number

Tags: java, regex

Sorry, yet another regex question! I have a string of unknown length that contains the following pattern:

```
"abc1defg2hijk23lmn19"
```

I need to split the string to get the following:

```
["abc1", "DefG2", "hiJk23", "lmn19"]
```

Its pretty simple I just need to split after the number each time. The number can be any non zero number.

I can do a positive lookup like this:

```
a.split("(?=\\d+)");
```

However, that actually splits out the number rather than the group of letter in front and the number.

My current attempt looks like this but doesn't work:

```
a.split("(?=[A-Za-z]+\\d+)");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So for input

```
abc1defg2hijk23lmn19
```

you want to find places marked with `|`

```
abc1|defg2|hijk23|lmn19
```

In other words you want to find place which

- has digit before `(?<=[0-9])`
- and alphabetic after `(?=[a-zA-Z])` it

(I assume you are familiar with [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanisms).

In that case use

```
split("(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-zA-Z])")
```

which means place between digit and alphabetic character like `1|a` where `|` represents such place.

---

Example:

```
String data ="abc1defg2hijk23lmn19";
for (String s: data.split("(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-zA-Z])"))
    System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
abc1
defg2
hijk23
lmn19
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex fpr splitting:

```
(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bT9jJ4)

Answer (score 2):

replace the number with the number + a space, then split on space.

```
a = a.replaceAll("[0-9]+","$1 ");
String[] b = a.split(" ");
```

It can also be customized in case your string contains other spaces, by substituting a character guaranteed not to appear in your string instead of the space. my favorite is (§).